# Character jumps only when player touch and release finger Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a 2D platformer mobile game I'm about to release soon but there is this issue bothers me and appearently my testers.

In the game, you must touch screen to jump. But character only jumps when you touch and release your finger. This causes delay and affect gameplay badly. I need it to jump immediately when player touch. Not after releasing her/his finger.

Here is the code block jumps the character:

```
public void Jump(){
        if (currentJumpRights > 0){
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up*jumpForce,ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            soundManager.PlaySound("jumpSound");
            currentJumpRights--;
        }
}
```

I have an invisible jump button that covers most of the screen to prevent jumping when player clicks pause button. And this function is assigned to that invisible button.

How can I achieve this? Thanks for help!

Comment: don't use a UI button for this, you could just use the Input class to do this, there are examples of how to detect touch input on the [Input.GetTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) docs page

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Button` (since you don't want any visual effects anyway) you can use `IPointerDownHandler` interface and do e.g.

```
public class MyButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public UnityEvent onClick;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        onClick.Invoke();
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // not doing anything but from the Documentation I'm never sure if needed
        // "Note: In order to receive OnPointerUp callbacks, you must also implement the IPointerDownHandler interface"
        // Not sure if this also goes for the other direction ;)
    }
}
```

This way you receive the callback immediately when pressing down instead of "clicking".

---

If you rather want the button to continuously trigger as long as it stays pressed you can extend this and do e.g.

```
public class MyButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public UnityEvent onPointerDown;
    public UnityEvent onPointerUp;
    public UnityEvent whilePressed;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        onPointerDown.Invoke();

        StartCoroutine(PressedRoutine);
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        onPointerUp.Invoke();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // nothing but needed for exit event
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        onPointerUp.Invoke();
    }

    private IEnumerator PressedRoutine()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            yield return null;
            whilePressed.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```